# restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following configuration for my pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  serviceName: my-app
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: myregistry:443/mydomain/my-app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

And it deploys fine without the restartPolicy. However, I do not want the process to be run again once finished, hence I added the 'restartPolicy: Never'. Unfortunately I get the following error when I attempt to deploy:

```
Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "stack.yaml": StatefulSet.apps "my-app" is invalid: spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725

It appears that only "Always" is supported.

Comment: To anyone that is interested, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893238/kubernetes-how-to-run-job-only-once/39894448#39894448) on how to create a pod to run once.

Comment: I was also expecting to be able to set `deployment.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy ` to "Never" or "OnFailure"! I read the link provided by @max23_. I suppose one could use `backoffLimit: 0`, though it doesn't seem like a robust solution as the reason why the pod terminated could very well be an actual failure!

Comment: This is insane and always has been. Please change this.

Comment: The most insane part is that, to this day, the documentation clearly states that `Never` is supported: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy

Comment: The documentation is not fixed. I guess its only for deployments. For "Pod" it should still work.

Answer (score 13):

You should use a [Job controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) instead of a StatefulSet:

> A Job creates one or more Pods and ensures that a specified number of
>   them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job
>   tracks the successful completions.

Take a look at [Handling Pod and Container Failures](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures) section, which explains the effects of using `restartPolicy` with values `OnFailure` or `Never`, combined with another configs such as `parallelism`, `completions` and `backoffLimit`.

Comment: The problem of Jobs is the fact they are immutable, one can't edit it just like we can edit deployments