# How to ensure that a pod does not restart?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod that is meant to run a code excerpt and exit afterwards. I do not want this pod to restart after exiting, but apparently it is not possible to set a restart policy in Kubernetes (see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169169/4828060)).

Therefore my question is: how can I implement a pod that runs only once?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deploy a job. A deployment is meant to keep the containers running all the time. Give a check on:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/