# Run a Kubernetes Jobs only Once

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run a kubernetes Job exactly once. This may by a script that will do some database updates. We dont want for any reason, that script to be executed more than once.

Any suggestion, how can we do it with kubernetes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes - how to run job only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893238/kubernetes-how-to-run-job-only-once)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Job resource, with the `backoffLimit` set to 0, like the following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example
          image: alpine:3
          command: ["sh", "-c", "exit 1"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Afthe the job has run once, if it fails, it will reach the backoffLimit, and will not retry. If you describe the job, you can verify it:

```
Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  117s  job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit
```